# Ramda - get ids from nested array of multiple objects

Tags: ramda.js

I am trying to get `outgoingNodes` IDs which are stored in array which is inside objects like in example below but I have no idea where to start...:

```
const nodes = {
    "818": {
        "id": "818",
        "index": 1,
        "outgoingNodes": [
            "819"
        ],
    },
    "819": {
        "id": "819",
        "outgoingNodes": [
            "820",
            "821"
        ],
    }
}
```

I would like to get an array of IDs as a result. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the values (sub objects), pluck the `outgoingNodes` arrays, and flatten to a single array:

```js
const { pipe, values, pluck, flatten } = R

const fn = pipe(
  values,
  pluck('outgoingNodes'),
  flatten
)

const nodes = {"818":{"id":"818","index":1,"outgoingNodes":["819"]},"819":{"id":"819","outgoingNodes":["820","821"]}}

const result = fn(nodes)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Another option is to combine getting the `outgoingNodes` arrays, and flattening to a single array using R.chain with R.prop:

```js
const { pipe, values, chain, prop } = R

const fn = pipe(
  values,
  chain(prop('outgoingNodes')),
)

const nodes = {"818":{"id":"818","index":1,"outgoingNodes":["819"]},"819":{"id":"819","outgoingNodes":["820","821"]}}

const result = fn(nodes)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for help :) This time I was not even close to the proper solution so you saved me a lot of time